# webpage to present short texts (e.g. twitter feeds, quotes, etc...) in nice graphicar manner (html5?)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a screen that will serve as a display for short texts - either floating from bottom to top (like credits shown at the end of the movie) or maybe like sentences typed on a typewriter (letter by letter) and then dissolving. While I think I have all the knowhow to make it in csharp I would like to try something new and make it available as a webpage. What is important is the design - nice fonts, full screen with animations and colors.

Could you please advice where to start with this? I guess this is an HTML5/JavaScript topic - am I right? Any guidance (*tutorial, sample, library to use, or a google search query*) will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a cool app demoed at Google I/O this year that does something similar to what you're asking for.  The presentation and demo are here:

http://youtu.be/yd30Nmb3mPU?t=4m30s

And the demo Twitter feed app can be found here:

http://html5-intro.appspot.com/TweetReader/index.html#

You can "view source" to see how they did it.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into that.  After further googling for a while I have found various

    <marquee>

examples which did not look very well (scrolling had some frame drops?) and this: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crosstick.htm which is moving 

    <div>

tags on the screen - this will be the one I will use probably in case the tweeterFall will be to hard for me to decompose.

Comment: I cannot get the TweeterFall to work - in Firefox it shows nothing, in IExplorer it asks for Chrome install (and I cannot reject this window :()